# How to install Gearman Job Server with PHP

Tags: php, centos, task-queue, gearman

I am trying to install Gearman client worker on Centos server. PHP has been installed and all required `gearman-php` module also installed. when executing command `gearmand -d` it gets executed successfully.

But when myClientProgram.php assign job to the worker it throws warning:

```
[Thu Oct 06 03:47:26.293204 2022] [:error] [pid 20990] [client 202.173.125.72:6049] PHP Warning:  GearmanClient::addServer(): 127.0.0.1:4730:4730 getaddrinfo:Name or service not known pid(20990) in /gearman/gearmanManager.class.php on line 28
[Thu Oct 06 03:47:26.293359 2022] [:error] [pid 20990] [client 202.173.125.72:6049] PHP Warning:  GearmanClient::doBackground(): _client_run_task(GEARMAN_NO_SERVERS) no servers provided -&gt; libgearman/run.cc:68: pid(20990) in /gearman/gearmanManager.class.php on line 32
```

When I try to print error using PHP's error_get_last I get below message:

```
[message] => GearmanClient::doBackground(): _client_run_task(GEARMAN_NO_SERVERS) no servers provided -> libgearman/run.cc:68: pid(20989)
```

And when I check status of assigned job using command: `gearadmin  --status | sort -n | column -t` nothing gets displayed only one "dot" display in output of above command.

How can I solve this issue? I have gone through many similar questions but not able to find any solution which could work for me.

Comment: How do you have the host defined? It looks like you might have the port where you don't need it.

Comment: $client->addServer('127.0.0.1:4730'); but without defining this another error comes. PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'GearmanException' with message 'Failed to set exception option' in /gearman/gearmanManager.class.php:29 where on line 29 it is mentioned $client->addServer();

Comment: Remove the port. 4730 is default, and if you need to pass it in, [it needs to be done separately, per the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/gearmanclient.addserver.php)

Comment: i got above mentioned error. checked in error log.  tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36151874/gearman-php-failed-to-set-exception-option might be of some help

Comment: You said "without defining this". Did you remove the whole string? You just need `127.0.0.1`, which is the localhost ip. `4730` is the port that doesn't need to be added to that string.

Comment: i did the way you mentioned above  $client->addServer('127.0.0.1);

Comment: Gone through the question whose link you shared above, done whatever mentioned there but still same issue.

Comment: tail -f /var/log/gearmand.log shows error : ERROR 2022-10-05 21:06:36.000000 [  main ] Timeout occured when calling bind() for 0.0.0.0:4730 -> libgearman-server/gearmand.cc:679

Answer (score 0, accepted):

credit for this solution to be given to my friend, he has asked me to run two commands:

```
getenforce
setenforce 0
```

Post that all my mentioned error vanished.